# PHP & Ajax: Passing time_zone as a parameter in AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to pass the time zone parameter in a Ajax request

Like

```
 alert(meeting_time);
        alert(meeting_timezone);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "GET",  
        url: "http://webfaction/UI/user/joinmeeting.php",  
        data: "user_names="+ user_names + "&image=" +file+"&duration="+ duration +"&user_name="+ user_name + "&meeting_id=" + meeting_id + "&moderator_password=" + moderator_password +"&attendee_password=" + attendee_password +
        "&meeting_time=" + meeting_time + "&meeting_timezone=" + meeting_timezone + "&meeting_sms_no=" + meeting_sms_no + "&meeting_logout_url=" + meeting_logout_url +"&meeting_maxp=" + meeting_maxp +"&meeting_name=" + meeting_name ,
        success: function(json){  
               alert(json);
              $('#show_ajax').hide();
            if(!json.error) location.reload(true);

        },
```

Now my problem is before ajax request

```
alert(meeting_timezone);  is printing  `GMT +8.00`
```

but on the joinmeeting.php page

```
   $meeting_timezone = $_GET['meeting_timezone'];   

   print $meeting_timezone;
```

the above print statement is printing the value `GMT 8.00`

(+ sign is not printing here)

Please tell me how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a known situation while using POST and GET methods, your + signs will be converted to space. The right way to pass data through POST or GET is using `encodeURIComponent` in JavaScript.

For example in your case, do this before sending:

```
meeting_timezone = encodeURIComponent(meeting_timezone);
```

Comment: thanks man even i also found the same solution but one more thing can i put parameter string inside URIComponent ?

Comment: You can put any string you are passing in that function, but don't put whole of URL in it, use it like this:
'url.php?a=' + encodeURIComponent(SOMETHING) + '&b=' + encodeURIComponent(SOMETHINGELSE)

Take a look at the link @YAAK provided in his answer for more info ...

Answer (score 0):

It will help if you encode your URL in JavaScript by

```
encodeURIComponent(uri)
```

Like this:

```
data: encodeURIComponent(("user_names="+ user_names + "&image=" +file+"&duration="+ duration +"&user_name="+ user_name + "&meeting_id=" + meeting_id + "&moderator_password=" + moderator_password +"&attendee_password=" + attendee_password +
        "&meeting_time=" + meeting_time + "&meeting_timezone=" + meeting_timezone + "&meeting_sms_no=" + meeting_sms_no + "&meeting_logout_url=" + meeting_logout_url +"&meeting_maxp=" + meeting_maxp +"&meeting_name=" + meeting_name )
```

Also take a look at this question:

[How to encode a URL in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

might be useful

Comment: thanks this also helps me but i can not accept more then one answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the `data:` parameter as a string, use an object:

```
data: { user_names: user_names,
        image: file,
        ...
        meeting_timezone: meeting_timezone,
        ...
      }
```

jQuery will then take care of converting it to a query string properly.